# Subset dataframe based on field

Tags: python, pandas

```
mukey   cokey     hzdept_r  hzdepb_r
422927  11090397    0        20
422927  11090397    20       71
422927  11090397    71       152
422927  11090398    0        18
422927  11090398    18       117
422927  11090398    117      152
```

I would like to subset the dataframe above, such that only the FIRST SET of cokey's (in this case 11090397) are selected. Of course, since this is a sample dataset, the solution needs to scale to larger versions of such a  dataframe.

In this case, the resulting dataset should be:

```
mukey   cokey     hzdept_r  hzdepb_r
422927  11090397    0        20
422927  11090397    20       71
422927  11090397    71       152
```

I have tried using groupby, but not sure how to select only the first cokey value from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another method is to just take the first unique value:

```
In [97]:

df[df['cokey'] == df['cokey'].unique()[0]]
Out[97]:
    mukey     cokey  hzdept_r  hzdepb_r
0  422927  11090397         0        20
1  422927  11090397        20        71
2  422927  11090397        71       152
```

You could also use integer based indexing to get the first value for filtering:

```
In [99]:

df[df['cokey'] == df['cokey'].iloc[0]]
Out[99]:
    mukey     cokey  hzdept_r  hzdepb_r
0  422927  11090397         0        20
1  422927  11090397        20        71
2  422927  11090397        71       152
```

Comment: Is there an advantage in the first unique value, over the first value?

Comment: not really, it's just another method of getting values from a df

Comment: unique documentation doesn't specify that it maintains order, tho.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for the first all of the cokey's in the df that are equal to the first cokey in the df, use:

```
test[test['cokey'] == test.cokey[0]]
```

Edit:
@dsm is right, the code above will you give you the cokey of index zero, so if your df doesn't have an autoimcremented index starting at zero, you might not get the actual desired result.  Instead use:

```
test[test['cokey'] == test.iloc[0]['cokey']]
```

Comment: thanks Liam, but hard coding 11090397 will not work, since the larger dataframe can have other values for cokey.

Comment: @user308827 Ah, so you just want the first set, no matter what it is?

Comment: Exactly! I will update the question to reflect this.

Comment: `test.cokey[0]` doesn't give the first cokey (although it might); it gives the one associated with the index 0.  `.iloc[0]` gives the first.

Answer (score 2):

if df is the sample dataframe:

```
cokeys = set(df.cokey) #unique keys
for k in cokeys:
    print df[df.cokey==k] #sub-dataframes
```

result:

```
    mukey     cokey  hzdept_r  hzdepb_r
0  422927  11090397         0        20
1  422927  11090397        20        71
2  422927  11090397        71       152
    mukey     cokey  hzdept_r  hzdepb_r
3  422927  11090398         0        18
4  422927  11090398        18       117
5  422927  11090398       117       152
```

if you literally only want the first dataframe, let `k=df.iloc[0].cokey`.